# react-scroll scrollToBottom not working when scroll to x does work

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

I am using  react-scroll npm package from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Following their example, I have set up my code and I can get the onClick functions to work for scrolling a specific distance but the scrollToBottom still does not work.

I have also set up my code slightly differently than their example as `this.scrollToBottom` was throwing errors and so was `React.createClass`.

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.scss'
import { Link, DirectLink, Element, Events, animateScroll as scroll, scrollSpy, scroller } from 'react-scroll'


 
const Header = () => ({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    Events.scrollEvent.register('begin', function(to, element) {
      console.log('begin', arguments);
    });
 
    Events.scrollEvent.register('end', function(to, element) {
      console.log('end', arguments);
    });
 
    scrollSpy.update();
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('begin');
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('end');
  },
  scrollToTop: function() {
    scroll.scrollToTop();
  },
  scrollToBottom: function() {
    scroll.scrollToBottom();
  },
  handleSetActive: function(to) {
    console.log(to);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="Header">
            <div className="Header-div1">
                <h3 className="Header-div1__name">Caleb Middleton</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="Header-div2">
                <p className="Header-div2__About margin-right" onClick={() => scroll.scrollToBottom}>About</p>
                <p className="Header-div2__Skills margin-right" onClick={() => scroll.scrollTo(500)}>Skills</p>
                <p className="Header-div2__Projects margin-right" onClick={() => scroll.scrollTo(900)}>Projects</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
})

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`create-react-class`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class) if you want to retain this syntax.

Run `npm i create-react-class` and include it in your project:

```
const createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

const Header = createReactClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    ...
```

As for the `scrollToBottom` issues, currently you are just passing a function but not executing it. Refactor it like this:

```
<p className="Header-div2__About margin-right" onClick={() => scroll.scrollToBottom()}>About</p>
```

[image: Edit still-brook-qhgmo]

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html

---

Alternatively, you can convert your `Header` component to a class that extends [`React.Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and follow the syntax of a JavaScript class.